# Prisma URL string for MySQL connection via sockets

Tags: mysql, connection-string, prisma, .env

According to Prisma docs the template for the connection string using sockets is:

```
mysql://USER:POST@localhost/database?socket=/var/run/mysql/
```

Based on this I've created the following, changing the **USER** to `root`, database to my `issue_tracker` database and the location of the socket query string for my Ubuntu 22.04 installation which is **/var/run/mysqld/** so my string is:

```
mysql://root:POST@localhost/issue_tracker?socket=/var/run/mysqld/
```

What I'm unsure of is what I'm supposed to replace **POST** with. If I leave it as the above and try to run a migration I get the following error:

```
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`3306`

Please make sure your database server is running at `localhost`:`3306`.
```

What is **POST** field after user field in the Prisma example template supposed to represent?

Comment: "POST" should be your MySQL user's password. I see on [this page](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mysql) the writer wrote "USER:POST" in one case, but elsewhere on the same documentation page it says "USER:PASSWORD". It seems like the writer just made an editing mistake.

Comment: this mean your socket has another name or isn't reachable

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on using the default mysql socket connection method that was configured automatically during the Ubuntu installation instructions and used the following command to change the mysql authentication plugin from `auth_socket` to `caching_sha2_password`. This is done using the following from the mysql command-line:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'new-password-here';
```

I could then simply refer to Prisma docs to use the connection string pattern discussed under **Base URL and path**, specifically the string pattern:

```
mysql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE
```

Prisma migrations now work.

FYI. This is for MySQL version 8.0.35